# How to disable auto-pause for YouTube

Tags: youtube, brave

Originally I thought this was a browser issue, but it turns out to be an actual YouTube issue.
I'm using Brave Version 0.62.51. Every time I play YouTube, after 10 minutes the video will pause and ask if I am still listening.

> Video paused. Continue watching? 
>   YES

[image]

How do I disable this feature? Or at least extend the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can. Apparently it exists in YouTube Red as well.

There's a Chrome extension however. No idea about Brave.
[YouTube NonStop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-nonstop/nlkaejimjacpillmajjnopmpbkbnocid?hl=en)

Comment: Most Chrome extensions can work on Brave because it's based on Webkit. It's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround (only work with playlists):

1. Start playlist
2. Then go back (the playlist will go to the bottom right corner)
3. And that's it. Now auto-pause is not working ...